# How to get all audio file from internal and external storage of a device in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am trying to make a music player using flutter. For this I need to fetch the audio file from internal and external storage of the device. I know there is a package called [flute_music_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flute_music_player) but it shows plugin incompatibility errors. Is there any way of getting audio file from device in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `but it shows plugin incompatibility errors.` can you show the errors?

Did you follow all instructions to use the plugin?

Or you can try using others plugins like:

- [on_audio_query](https://github.com/LucasPJS/on_audio_query)